# Big Query Loop through Start and End date

Tags: sql, performance, loops, google-bigquery, date-range

I have a table with Start and end date with the Interval of 6 months. Below is one example:

```
Row   start_date  end_date
1     2018-09-18   2019-03-18
2     2019-03-18   2019-09-18
3     2019-09-18  2020-03-18
```

I have a master table (which is very big), So I have loop through this start_date and end_date and insert the record selected into the different table. Below is the sample query.

```
     create table dataset.t1 (v1,v2,v3,create_dt);
    
    LOOP
    
        insert into dataset.t1 (v1,v2,v3,create_dt) select v1,v2,v3,create_dt 
    from dataset.t2 where create_dt >= (select start_date from dataset.t1) 
    and create_date < (select end_date from dataset.t1)

END LOOP.
```

When I tried with Loop I am getting below error:

```
Query error: Scalar subquery produced more than one element at.
```

Could anyone please help me on how to implement this. My final goal is to improve performance by dividing the date into different ranges.

Comment: Can you update your question with the desired output that you are looking for based on the input data that you have provided?

Answer (score 0):

On the error that you've got, the problem is your `(select start_date from dataset.t1)` returns more than one element, not sure what you want to achieve but in order for the subquery to work, it should be something like `(select MIN(start_date) from dataset.t1)`.

I don't understand your loop because nothing seems changed in your loop (beside you're inserting something to t1), you should think about when your loop should exit.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Ok if I give min(start_date) from dataset.t1 then I will be looping one start date and end date. I am confused on using the looping through start_dates , end_dates and how to exit the loop.Any inputs will help

Comment: @Kosalya please see example with using start_date here: https://github.com/anand-eyunni/BigQuery

Comment: Thanks everyone, I did resolved by adding counter to the table which has date and exit the loop when the counter hits maximum.

Answer (score 0):

The below works in SQl server. You will have to find Big data equivalent for cursor. You can use an array to hole the start & end dates and loop through.
You can create a temporary table for storing the Start date & Enda date and called it `#temp_db`. Open a cursor and fetch the first start date & end date into a variable.from `#temp_db`.

`select start_date,end_date into @start_date,@end_date from #temp_db`

Execute the Sql:
Insert into `#new_tbl`

`select * from #src_tbl where create_dt >= @start_date and create_dt < @end_date`.

For every record, fetched from the `#temp_db`, start inserting into a new table/same table as per your request.
When there is no more row to fetch from your`#temp_db`..you would have inserted all the records into the `#new_tbl`.